# Get input text by php code

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, input

I need to get the text from an input in my code, and put it like a php variable in the same php file:

**Input code part :**

```
<input width="600px" type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class="search_box" placeholder="">
```

**PHP Parameter part :**

```
<form method="post" name="searchform" action="search/<?php echo (xyx) ?>">
```

How I get the input text in the **(xyx)** part of the code?

---

**Complete code :**

```
    <div class="tipobusqueda" id="tipobusqueda">        
    <text style="color:#000">Filtrar por :</text>
    <form method="post" name="searchform" action="search/<?php echo $value['Id_Cliente'] ?>">
        <select id="tiposearch" name="tiposearch" style="width: 100px">
            <option value="Nombre">Nombre</option>
            <option value="Apellidos">Apellidos</option>
            <option value="NIF">NIF</option>
            <option value="Dirección">Direcci&oacute;n</option>
            <option value="Teléfono">Tel&eacute;fono</option>
            <option value="Estado">Estado</option>
        </select>

        <input width="600px" type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class="search_box" placeholder="">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="search_button"><!--&nbsp;Filtrar texto&nbsp;-->
        <br />
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is $value['Id_Cliente'], and i dont understand what you want to do ?

Comment: PHP is a server-side language, so you'll need to submit the form in order to access its variables. Where is $value['Id_Cliente'] coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tipobusqueda" id="tipobusqueda">        
            <text style="color:#000">Filtrar por :</text>
            <form method="post" name="searchform">
                <select id="tiposearch" name="tiposearch" style="width: 100px">
                    <option value="Nombre">Nombre</option>
                    <option value="Apellidos">Apellidos</option>
                    <option value="NIF">NIF</option>
                    <option value="Dirección">Direcci&oacute;n</option>
                    <option value="Teléfono">Tel&eacute;fono</option>
                    <option value="Estado">Estado</option>
                </select>
                <input width="600px" type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class="search_box" placeholder="">
                <input type="button" value="Search" class="search_button">
                <br />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    $('.search_button').click(function(){
        location.href='search/'+$('#search_box').val();
    });
</script>
```